# Cannot set property of undefined - Global objects and namespacing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, window, global-variables, globalization

I'm using a variable attached to the window:

`window.App`

As a reference point for the rest of my variables within my application. However, when I attempt to do this:

```
window.App = {};

App.Views.User.Login = /* Login View Instance */;
```

It will complain about `Views` not being defined. This is fine for the most part because I can  predefine `App.Views, App.Models, App.Collections`, etc.

However when we get into the submodules that aren't always needed (`App.Views.User`) I would prefer for this to be loaded when needed...

Is the only option the following?

```
if( ! App.Views.User ) { App.Views.User = {}; };

App.Views.User.Login = /* Login View Instance */;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start your submodules like this:

```
App.Views.User = App.Views.User || {};
App.Views.User.Login = new Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({});
```

Only marginally cleaner than what you have already but that's generally what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
namespace("myapp.mymodule.submodule.component",{});
```

where:

```
function namespace (ns, module, optional_root) {
    var root = optional_root || window,
        array = ns.split("."),
        name = "",
        component_name = array.pop(),

        i = 0, l = array.length;

    for (; i < l; i += 1) {
        name = array[i];
        root[name] = root[name] || {};
        root = root[name];
    }

    root[component_name] = module;
}
```

This should allow you to write:

```
namespace("Appname.module.component", {});
```

Where the function will expect to find `window.Appname`, or like:

```
namespace("module.component", function(){}, Myapp);
```

Where you tell it to start by defining `module` in `Myapp`, if it doesn't exist.

Only downside would be that the function would have to exist before you load modules.